# Extract email from string using regexp with Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, email

I am new to Perl and I am trying to extract email from string 
"Tom Smith" `<tomsmith@gmail.com>`
The problem is that the module Email::Address is not installed and I don't have permissions to install it.
Is there any way to extract email using regexp.

Comment: There're thousands of them: https://www.google.com/search?q=email+regexp

Comment: `/^.*<([^>])>/`, assuming the address is always inside `<>`

Comment: @kirilloid i think you should answer the question instead of just giving a google search link...

Comment: @TamikSoziev I'm not a specialised in parsing emails with regexs, so I help as much as I can.

Comment: @Michael i tried like this $val =~ /^.*<([^>])>/; Does not work.

Comment: @Michael Using `/^.*` is redundant. You also forgot the quantifier. `/<([>]+)>/` is the regex you meant.

Comment: @TLP `/<([^>]+)>/` You forgot the `^`

Comment: @TLP
my $val = 'Tom Smith <tomsmith@gmail.com>';
$val =~ /<([^>]+)>/;
print $val;
still prints this
Tom Smith <tomsmith@gmail.com>

Comment: Was doing wrong output, this worked print $val =~ /<([^>]+)>/;
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/<(.*)>/` it will grab a text inside < > brackets

Comment: This helped print $val =~ /^.*<(.*)>.*/;

Comment: you can also do: `if($val =~ m/^.*<(.*)>.*/){ print "The email is $1."; }`

Comment: There is no need to have a .* anchored to the start of the string. Nor is there any need to have a trailing .*.

Additionally the captured .* will also match on > characters.

Comment: @RobertDuncan his string is: `"Tom Smith" <tomsmith@gmail.com>` , if you remove `.*` from the beginning it wont be matched. Also he said its working for him, why downvote?

Comment: @TamikSoziev Did you try removing the leading and trailing .*? They are not required. 

perl -e '($email) = q{"Tom Smith" <tomsmith@gmail.com>} =~ /<(.*)>/; print "$email\n"'

Comment: @RobertDuncan they are not required, but both regexps work. (With a differnce in first return value, though)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $from_address = q{"Tom Smith" <tomsmith@gmail.com>};
my ($email) = $from_address =~ m/<([^>]+)>/;
print "$email\n";
```

This will grab all of the content out of the first string of 1 or more non-`>` characters enclosed within angle brackets.

N.B. This does not validate that the email address is correctly formed. If you want to make sure that the content you have extracted from the <> format is valid, which you should, then you should look at https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Email-Address-1.895/lib/Email/Address.pm